# Confusing behaviour with basic type boolean in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

From TypeScript webpage: "The most basic datatype is the simple true/false value, which JavaScript and TypeScript call a boolean value."

Ok so far so good, it's just like a normal boolean in JS or Java, but when I do this:

```
var a = false; // boolean
// alternative declaration
// var a: boolean = false; 

// ... do whatever with "a"

if (a == true) // or using ===
{
    console.log("true");
}
```

I get an error saying:
Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'false' and 'true'.
One possible solution is to cast "a" to any, since this works:

```
if ((a as any) == true)
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need to compare true/false values with ==/=== because they are already boolean values themselves. thus making it redundant.

so just do `if (a)` or `if (!a)`

typescript just wants to optimize your code this way. in vanilla JS it is perfectly fine to do `if (a === true)`

Comment: Makes perfect sense, but wasn't used to this behaviour

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11178#issuecomment-249877718

> This is working as intended. The compiler performs control flow analysis and knows that p has the actual value Place.Left where you're performing the === operations, and it is calling out that it makes no sense to compare a value that is known to be Place.Left to a value that is known to be Place.Right. It's effectively like writing Place.Left === Place.Right or 1 === 2, both of which would also produce errors.

You get the error message because TypeScript also warns about possible developer errors. As you set `a` to *false* (and never change it), it makes no sense to check for `a == true` as that is never true in your code. Essentially, TypeScripts warns you about dead code.

Comment: In this example you are right about dead code, but I had the same problem in the real code where that boolean value can change

Comment: @BakedInhalf if you got that message in real code you should post a question with actual code that shows the error: probably you have a mistake somewhere which means even though you think the value can vary in practice it cannot. Or you are using casts to hide the change from typescript.

Comment: @Duncan No mistake. It's simply not possible to write a == true in typescript. I have marked the correct answer

Comment: @BakedInhalf You are wrong about that, e.g. `var a = !!Math.random(); if (a == true) {}`. TypeScript will/should only warn about it when it can safely infer the value of `a`.

Comment: @BakedInhalf it is completely possible to use `== true` or even `=== true`, but it is almost always the wrong thing to do in any language not just typescript.